# Can't create simple array in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Here's my problem:

I want to create an array of Strings with the code

```
var data = [String]()
```

now..

I get an exception.
(Can anyone tell me where the stack trace is? I'm new to xcode.)

Here's the screenshot:

[Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewERh.png)
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an exception, you have two breakpoints set up, just remove it or disable and it should be fine. 
You can use shortcut cmd+Y to disable/enable all of them.